# Finding all natural numbers $ $x and $ y$?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've been asked to find all natural numbers $x$ and $ y$ satisfying $x^2 + 1 = y(y+1$) where $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$. I have no clue how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

$(x,y)=(1,1)$ is a solution. Now let us suppose that $y\ge 2$. Then
$$
y^2+1 < y(y+1) < (y+1)^2+1.
$$

Comment: Where exactly did you derive that inequality from?

Comment: @runesbane $y(y+1)=y^2+y$ is strictly greater than $y^2+1$. On the other hand, $y(y+1)$ is smaller than $(y+1)^2<(y+1)^2+1$.

Comment: Okay, I vaguely see what you're saying there, but I'm still not sure how I would show how I got there or how to find all the natural numbers using that, this problem may just be above my level of math, it was given to us a challenge problem in calc2.

Comment: @runesbane I don't find it particularly related to Calculus. Anyway, from the fact that there exists an integer $m=m(y)$ such that $m^2+1<y(y+1)<(m+1)^2+1$ you can conclude that, if $y>1$, then there are no other solutions.

Comment: I don't see how its related to Calculus either. But yeah, from looking at the original equation I was thinking 1 was probably the only answer. I'm following your logic from your last comment as to why it can only be 1 using that inequality, I'm just not seeing how you can assume that inequality to be true based on (x,y) = (1,1). Also, I see that the y^2+1 part is just changing x to y, but where does (y+1)^2 + 1 (y^2 + 2y +2) come from?

Comment: @runesbane Ok the original equation asks you to find all $y\ge 1$ such that $y(y+1)$ can be written in the form $x^2+1$, for some integer $x\ge 1$. Now, fix $y$, so that you have your number $y(y+1)$. Consider the sequence of numbers $1^2+1$, $2^2+1$, ... If you manage to show that your $y(y+1)$ is "between" $m^2+1$ and $(m+1)^2+1$ then you are done. Ok, now you can choose $m=y$..

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+1=y(y+1) \implies x^2-y^2=y-1 \implies (x-y)(x+y)=y-1$$

For $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$,

**Case I**

If $x=y$, then $y=1 \implies x=1$

**Case II**

If $x \ne y$, then $(x+y)$ divides $(y-1)$

But $x+y > y-1$, which is impossible.

> Hence, $$(x,y)=(1,1)$$
>   is the only natural number solutions

Answer (score 0):

$y^2 + y - x^2-1 = 0\implies \triangle = 1 - 4(-x ^2-1) = 4x^2 + 5=k^2\implies 5 = (k-2x)(k+2x)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Umm...I am only in Calculus 2 so I am not really sure what to do with that.

Comment: @runesbane, if you want "better" answers, then you should provide more context.  In your question you mention nothing about only having a Calc 1/2 background (that should be included in your context).